# 2-D distance for Kalman measurements

Tags: algorithm, matlab, kalman-filter

I have designed a simple 3-state (x,x-dot,x-dot-dot) Kalman filter which is updated by measurements for x and x-dot. The filter is tracking a peak on a surface in the x/x-dot plane. At each iteration, I detect a number of peaks on the surface, each with an x/x-dot measurement pair.

I need to select the peak which is closest to the current state as input for the next filter iteration. At the moment I am simply finding the difference in the x and x-dot dimensions, scaling them so they are similar in scale, and then computing the 2-D distance. This has been working fine for me, but I know it is not the "right" way to calculate the distance.

Is there a way to use the Kalman variables to determine which measurement is closest to the current estimate?

Not sure where this belongs, so I've posted it in stack, dsp, math, and stats exchanges.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for either http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://stats.stackexchange.com/. Not sure which, though.

Comment: I would go with http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I suppose I'll try them all :)

Comment: Mahalanobis distance?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right way. Suppose you have your state vector for the current timestep as mu:

[image]

and corresponding standard deviations:

[image]

and a current measurement m:

[image]

You can define something like a "probability of presence" (it would be that, if your state vector was x and y coordinates). That formula is not so easy any more.

The "everything included" formula for a two-dimensional gaussian distribution is this:
[image: frim wikipedia] ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution))
Assuming your variables are independent (a high value of x says nothing about the value of x_dot) it simplifies to this:

[image]

This probably does not look simple for you. But it's really just typing numbers in. Now bear with me: This is a probability density. It's highest when the estimation is close to the current state. That is not very handy, because the lowest value is zero. A distant point gets a value near zero, but so does a point that is ten times further away. You's like a measurement that expresses this as well.

That's where the log-likelihood comes into play:

[image]

While it may not be obvious, this transforms the probability W into a quadratic cost function K. The greater the distance, the greater the cost. (The exponential cancels with the ln)

You can now calculate the cost for each pair of (m | x) and get a matrix. This matrix is then feed into a solver for [linear assignment problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) like the munkres algorithm or [this one on FX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26836-lapjv-jonker-volgenant-algorithm-for-linear-assignment-problem-v3-0).

Output is a assignment matrix that has ones for the corresponding pairs.

Please note: Including the variances in you calculations can be beneficial, but make sure they're right. They're wrong if the are close to zero, and the are too big if they span the whole domain of the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a bit more (power of posting), and decided the best way to scale x and x-dot is by the standard deviation, which is being tracked within the covariance matrix.

```
errX = (x_n - x_n-1)/sqrt(var(x));
errXdot = (xdot_n - xdot_n-1)/sqrt(var(xdot));
err2D = sqrt(errX^2 + errXdot^2);
```